# Class CamelCaseToSeparator not found when running zf show version

Tags: php, zend-framework, command-line-interface

I'm trying to set up my Zend installation but when I run `zf show version` in the CLI I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Filter\Word\CamelCaseToSeparator' not found in C:\Progr
>   am Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\php\php546x120828095553\ZendFramework-2.0.3\library\
>   Zend\Filter\Word\CamelCaseToDash.php on line 18

I haven't changed anything in the files and they're in the right place with the correct names and everything.

Does anyone of you know what the error could be?

Comment: I think your system doesn't see Zend library. Did you write path_to_library  to your PATH variable ?

Comment: Just in case. There is a space in your "C:\Progr am Files " between Progr and am. Must be a typo in your question but just in case:)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem when I had 2 zend framework libaries includes in php.ini file for zend framework 1 and 2 versions, when I left only one, this error disapeared.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.